# try to concatenate 2 strings, result ends in a lot of spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

```
select CONCAT(convert(char, 123), 'sda');
```

Or

```
select convert(char, 123) + 'sda'
```

Or

```
select ltrim(convert(char, 123) + 'sda')
```

Output is:

[image]

How can I get the output without those spaces?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Also, a `char` is a **fixed** width string, so you should expect spaces at the end of a string that's 3 characters long with you convert it to a `char(30)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is 2 fold. Firstly that you are converting to a `char`, which is a **fixed width** datatype, and secondly that you aren't defining the length of your `char`, therefore the default length is used. For `CAST` and `CONVERT` that's a `char(30)`.

So, what you have to start is `convert(char, 123)`. This converts the int `123` to the **fixed width** string `'123                           '`. Then you concatenate the `varchar(3)` value `'sda'` to that, resulting in `'123                           sda'`. This is working exactly as written, but clearly not as you intend.

The obvious fix would be to use a `varchar` and define a length, such as `CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar(5),123),'sda')` which would return `'123sda'`, however, all of the [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function's parameters are a string type:

> *string_value*
>
> A string value to concatenate to the other values. The `CONCAT` function requires at least two string_value arguments, and no more than 254 string_value arguments.

This means you can simply just pass the value `123` and it'll be implicitly cast to a string type: `CONCAT(123,'sda')`.

---

To reiterate my comment's link too: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `char` while you probably want `[n]varchar(...)`: the former pads the string with white spaces, while the latter does not:

```
concat(convert(varchar(10), 123), 'sda');
```

But simpler yet: `concat()` forces the conversion of its arguments to the correct datatype by default, so this should do it:

```
concat(123, 'sda')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in SQL Server, never us `char` or related string definitions without a length.  SQL Server requires a length and the default depends on the context.  If you depend on the default length your code has a bug just waiting to happen.

Second, `char` is almost never what you want.  It is a fixed length string, with shorter strings padded with spaces.

If you want an explicit conversion use `varchar`, variable length strings:

```
select convert(varchar(255), 123) + 'sda'
```

Or dispense with the explicit conversion and use `concat()`:

```
select concat(123, 'sda')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already pointed out the root cause of the issue, if you cannot edit the datatype, you can always use `SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(CONVERT(char,123)),'sda')`. Although it's highly recommended to either use `varchar(n)` or give exclusive length of `char` as it is kind of pointless to create fixed length string and then reduce the length by using `TRIM`. `varchar(30)` would perfectly fit in here as the length can still NOT exceed the 30 symbols, but would not use all the length if the string is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Lets refer to Microsoft docs:

> When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

So, You have `Convert(char, 123)`, and you did not specify the *n* for `char`, so your code is equal to `Convert(char(30), 123)`.

Now it is clear why you have many space characters. To resolve the problem simply use variant length character datatypes such as `varchar` instead, however I recommend you to always use character datatypes with length. (Same as what @GordonLinoff posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63467483/1666800)

```
select convert(varchar, 123) + 'sda'
```